# Non-cyclic remark paths in HIS Metrics

Tags: metrics, code-metrics

I am using [this metrics](https://emenda.com/his/) to prove a C code and I don't understand what the second metric means. What is non-cyclic remark paths? Can someone give me an example how to use it?